# WAR file does not work when compiled on different machines

Tags: java, maven

I compiled one of our Java Project through Maven (tomcat7 plugin) and was able to create `WAR` out of it successfully

However, our application works only when the  `WAR` was compiled on my `Desktop`.  When I deploy WAR created out of our `'build machine'` it does not work

Desktop Machine details

```
Windows 10

java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)

Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-25T00:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: D:\apache-maven-3.6.0-bin\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_172, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Build Machine details

```
Windows Server 2012

java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)

Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-25T00:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_251, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows server 2012 r2", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

War file sizes

```
Build Machine    94864473 MyProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
Desktop Machine  95647448 MyProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

There's a huge difference in SIZE of the WAR file.  But, there's no diff between the source code.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Have you unpacked and compared the WAR files?

Comment: If your WAR has SNAPSHOT dependencies, it is possible that either build server or your computer is more up to date and you get different results.